# the rss helper doesnt generate the index.rss

Tags: cakephp, components, cakephp-1.3

i have an issue trying to generate rss. I followed all the steps of http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1460/RSS, but when i try in the url my index.rss shows me only my index page not in xml format.

this is my index of post_Controller:

```
var $components = array('Session','RequestHandler');
var $helpers = array('Html','Form','Time','Text');

function index() {
if( $this->RequestHandler->isRss() ){ 
$posts = $this->Post->find('all', array('limit' => 20, 'order' => 'Post.created DESC'));     
$this->set(compact('posts'));
}
$this->set('title_for_layout', 'mi blog');
$this->Post->recursive = 1;
$this->set('posts', $this->paginate());

}
```

this is my layout in app/views/layouts/rss/default.ctp:

```
 echo $this->Rss->header();
 if (!isset($documentData)) {
 $documentData = array();
 }
 if (!isset($channelData)) {
 $channelData = array();
 }
 if (!isset($channelData['title'])) {
 $channelData['title'] = $title_for_layout;
 } 
 $channel = $this->Rss->channel(array(), $channelData, $content_for_layout);
 echo $this->Rss->document($documentData,$channel);
```

this the view in app/views/posts/rss/index.ctp

```
    $this->set('documentData', array(
    'xmlns:dc' => 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/'));

    $this->set('channelData', array(
    'title' => __("Articles", true),
    'link' => $this->Html->url('/', true),
    'description' => __("Articulos mas recientes.", true),
    'language' => 'en-us'));



    // content
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $postTime = strtotime($post['Post']['created']);

        $postLink = array(
            'controller' => 'posts',
            'action' => 'view',

            $post['Post']['id']);
        // You should import Sanitize
        App::import('Sanitize');
        // This is the part where we clean the body text for output as the description 
        // of the rss item, this needs to have only text to make sure the feed validates
        $bodyText = preg_replace('=\(.*?\)=is', '', $post['Post']['body']);
        $bodyText = $this->Text->stripLinks($bodyText);
        $bodyText = Sanitize::stripAll($bodyText);
        $bodyText = $this->Text->truncate($bodyText, 400, array(
            'ending' => '...',
            'exact'  => true,
            'html'   => true,
        ));

        echo  $this->Rss->item(array(), array(
            'title' => $post['Post']['title'],
            'link' => $postLink,
            'guid' => array('url' => $postLink, 'isPermaLink' => 'true'),
            'description' =>  $bodyText,
            'pubDate' => $post['Post']['created']));
    }
```

which could be the problem ... Also i have put the component in the app_controller.php
     var $components = array ('Auth', 'Session', 'RequestHandler'); 
but nothing happens the index.rss is the Same of posts / index

Comment: remember to add this code to config/routes.php Router::parseExtensions('rss');

Comment: yes I added it already..

Comment: I fixed the issue...but why in chrome the index.rss looks like this... <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2.0"><channel><title>latest posts</title>......     and in firefox looks fine??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not returning the RSS view in the index controller. Update the RSS section of the index function to return the rss view:

```
function index() {
  if( $this->RequestHandler->isRss() ){ 
    $posts = $this->Post->find('all', array('limit' => 20, 'order' => 'Post.created DESC'));     
    return $this->set(compact('posts'));
  }
// ...snip...
}
```

**UPDATE**

It's how Chrome handles the layout. I know it is horrible. FireFox and IE handle RSS layout much better. But you can install the RSS Layout extension for Chrome and it will format it the same way.

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd

Comment: I miss that return... but it works equally, now why in chrome just i see the xml format

Comment: It's the way chrome handles the layout. See my update in my answer on how to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

In the action of the controller. You must add

```
 $this->response->type("xml");
```

at the end.